# Docker run exits when running an amd64/python image

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, catboost

I am very elementary at Docker and I know a few commands to test my tasks. I have built a Docker image for 64-bit python because I had to install CatBoost in it. My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM amd64/python:3.9-buster
RUN apt update 
RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx apt-utils
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
# We copy just the requirements.txt first to leverage Docker cache
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip --default-timeout=100 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

I built the image with `docker build -t myimage .`, it gets built for a long time presumably successfully. When I run the image using the following command: `docker run -p 5000:5000 myimage`, it gives a warning `WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested` and downloads some things for while and then exits. Not sure whats happening. How do I tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by running the same thing on a linux machine.